# Project Euler no. 16

Tags: c

> 2^15 = 32768 and the sum of its digits is 3 + 2 + 7 + 6 + 8 = 26.
>   What is the sum of the digits of the number 2^1000?

I would like to solve the Project Euler problem No. 16. I am trying to save the power of 2's in an array. Suppose `2 ^ 6 = 128`. Then

```
int arr[1000];
arr[0] = 1 // or 8 (In other way also)
arr[1] = 2
arr[2] = 8 // or 1
// and so on....
```

But now the problem is how to solve this.

I am fetching problem in shifting the digit to next array location.
Suppose now,

```
arr[0] = 8;
```

In next iteration

```
arr[0] = 1; and array[1] = 6;
```

Here `arr[0]` contains 1 and `arr[1]` contains 6.
Next

```
arr[0] = 3;
arr[1] = 2;
....
....
//2 ^ 6
arr[0] = 1;
arr[1] = 2;
arr[2] = 8;
...
...
//2 ^ 10
arr[0] = 1;
arr[1] = 0;
arr[2] = 2;
arr[3] = 4;
.....
.....
```

and so on. Please help me.

Comment: I'd rather suppose that `2^7 == 128`. Just double the digits, and if the result is larger than 9, carry ten over to the next.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should go over each digit, starting with the least significant one, double it and add the carry from the previous one, store the result modulo 10 as the new digit value and if the result is more than 9, set the carry to 1 otherwise set it to 0 (or just perform integer division of the result by 10):

```
carry = 0
for i = 0 to MAX_DIGITS-1:
   tmp = 2 * digits[i] + carry
   digits[i] = tmp % 10
   carry = tmp / 10
```

(this is pseudocode - translate it to C for your own use)

---

Just as a side note, computing `2^1000` is extremly easy in binary - it is just `1` followed by 1000 `0`. Converting the result to decimal representation is a bit tricky but an efficient binary to BCD conversion methods exist. But I would still recommend that you use the GNU MP library instead. It only takes 6 lines to compute 2^1000 using GNU MP (the `#define` line and all whitespace lines are not counted):

```
#include <gmp.h>

#define MAX_DIGITS 302

mpz_t bignum;
char str[MAX_DIGITS+2];

mpz_init2(bignum, 1001);
mpz_ui_pow_ui(bignum, 2, 1000);  // set the integer object to 2^1000
mpz_get_str(str, 10, bignum);    // convert to base 10
```

Note that `2^1000` is 1001 binary digits and about 302 (equal to 1001*log(2)) decimal digits. Add two characters for a possible sign character and a `NULL` terminator character as requried by `mpz_get_str()`.

Now you only have to go over the resulting digits in `str`, convert them to integers and sum them all up.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void mul2(int *n){
    int c = 0, v;
    while(*n>=0){
        v  = c + *n * 2;
        c  = v / 10;
        *n++ = v % 10;
    }
    if(c) *n++ = c;//1
    *n = -1;//stopper
}

int sum(int *n){
    int sum=0;
    while(*n>=0)
        sum += *n++;
    return sum;
}

int main(void){
    int arr[1000] = {1, -1};//need 302 + 1, -1 is stoper
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<1000;i++)
        mul2(arr);
    printf("%d\n", sum(arr));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define POWER 1000

int digits[(POWER * 302 + 999)/1000] = {1}; // > log10(2 ** POWER)
int ndigits = 1;

int main(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < POWER; i++)
        for (int n = 0, j = 0;; j++)
        {
            n += digits[j] * 2;
            digits[j] = n % 10;
            n /= 10;
            if (j == ndigits - 1)
            {
                if (!n) break;
                ndigits++;
            }
        }

    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < ndigits; i++)
        sum += digits[i];

    printf("%d\n", sum);

    return 0;
}
```

Edit: A possibly faster but more obscure inner block:

```
            n += digits[j] * 2;
            if (n >= 10)
            {
                digits[j] = n - 10;
                n = 1;
                if (j == ndigits - 1)
                    ndigits++;
            }
            else
            {
                 digits[j] = n;
                 if (j == ndigits - 1)
                     break;
                 n = 0;
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my Python code:

```
b = 2**1000
c = str(b)

d = [ ]

for dig in c :

    d.append(int(dig))

e = sum(d)

print e
```

Comment: Eh python. You don't have to write a data type for extremely large numbers, thats's a great feature. But when you create a list just because you can call the sum method on it, I think there are problems. You don't have to store 1000 numbers in the memory just because you want the sum of them. Create a variable s and then increment it by the current element.

Answer (score 0):

```
    //Finally I did it.


    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//2 ^ 1000
int main()
{
   int array[1000] = { 0 };
   array[0] = 1;
   int i, j, cnt, div, carry, temp, sum;
   for(i = 0, cnt = 1; i < 1000; i++)
   {
       div = carry = 0;
       for(j = 0; j < 1000; j++)
       {
           if(carry != 0)
           {
               array[j] = (array[j] * 2) + carry;
               div = array[j] % 10;
               temp = array[j] / 10;
               array[j] = div ;//+ carry;
               carry = temp;
               //array[j] = (array[j] * 2) + 1;
               //carry = 0;
           }
           else
           {
               array[j] = array[j] * 2;
               if (array[j] > 9)
               {
                   div = array[j] % 10;
                   carry = array[j] / 10;
                   array[j] = div;
               }
           }

       }

   }
   sum = temp = 0;
   printf("The value of 2 ^ 1000 is : ");
for(i = 999; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if(array[i] || (temp))
    {
        temp++;
        sum = sum + array[i];
        printf("%d", array[i]);
    }

}
   printf("\nThe sum is : %d \n", sum);
   printf("\nThe number of digits are : %d \n", temp);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

int main() {

int a[10000]={0};
int m=1;
int carry=0;
a[0]=1;
long long int sum=0;
for(int i=1;i<=1000;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<m;j++)
    {
        int x=a[j]*2+carry;
        a[j]=x%10;
        carry=x/10;
    }
    while(carry!=0)
    {
        a[m++]=carry%10;
        carry/=10;
    }
  }
  for(int i=m-1;i>=0;i--)
   sum+=a[i];
  printf("%lld",sum);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[here's my java code to problem 16](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYbQ2.png)

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post and show the actual code as text instead of screenshots. Others can't copy and paste from your images. [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1402846) for details. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In this problem we can benefit from the computation for previous number.
for example to calculate `pow(2,1000)` we can use digits of `pow(2,999)`,
we can store digits of previous number in a queue. Current number can be obtained by multiplying digits of the previous number by 2 one by one.

In the below code above approach has been used:

```
using namespace std; 
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

int main() {

    queue<int> q;
    q.push(2);
    queue<int> q2;

    for (int i = 2; i <= 1000;i++) {

        int carry = 0;
        while (!q.empty())
        {
            int first = q.front();
            q.pop();
            int digit = (first * 2 + carry) % 10;
            carry = (first*2) / 10;
            q2.push(digit);
        }
        if(carry!=0) {
            q2.push(carry);
        }
        swap(q, q2);
    }

    int sum = 0;
    while(!q.empty()) {
        sum += q.front();
        q.pop();
    }
    cout << sum << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use string in order to find to solution. Here's my code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#define ll long long int
using namespace std;
int main(){
    vector<int> v;
    string s="1";  
    int r,n,res=0;  
    for(int i=0; i<1000; i++){
        r=0,n=0;
        for(int j=s.size()-1; j>=0; j--){
            n=r+(s[j]-'0')*2;
            v.push_back(n%10);
            r=n/10;
        }
        if(n>=10) v.push_back(n/10);
        s="";
        for(int k=v.size()-1; k>=0; k--){
            s+=to_string(v[k]);
        }
        v.clear();
    }
    for(int i=0; i<s.size(); i++){
        res+=(s[i]-'0');
    }
    cout<<res<<'\n';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{    
auto power=1000;
vector<int> result (1,2); // 
for(auto i =2; i<=power; i++ )
{
    auto carry =0;
    for (auto & elem : result)
    {
        auto mult = elem*2 + carry;
        if (mult > 9)
        {
            elem= mult-10;
            carry=1;
        }
        else
        {
            elem= mult;
            carry=0;
        }
    }
    if(carry)
        result.push_back(carry);

 }

auto sum=accumulate(result.begin(),result.end(),0);
cout<< "Euler 16: sum of the digits of 2^1000 ="<< sum << endl;
}
```